# Error when running "npx folio": First argument must use the object destructuring pattern: _x

Tags: playwright

I have playwright tests and I run the tests with this command: `npx folio`.

But when I run the tests I receive this error message:

`First argument must use the object destructuring pattern: _x`

I did try to delete the .babelrc file which should work according to this [thread](https://github.com/microsoft/folio/issues/160). But that didn't change anything for me.

What could be done to address this error?

Comment: A new version of folio got published with the potential fix included, would be great if you could check again. `npm install folio@0.3.18`

Comment: Thanks for your input. I'm using microsoft/playwright-test which has a dependency to folio@0.3.16. The recently added changes was basically just telling folio to ignore babelrc [here](https://github.com/microsoft/folio/commit/3d1fb21b5f2c460a46aa895aa8c551c3c22acc2b)  that is not my issue since deleting the babelrc file wouldn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

You would see this error if a function is provided to `beforeEach` or `afterEach` and doesn't take an object as its first parameter. So this won't work:

```
const before = (aFixture) => {...}
test.beforeEach(before);
```

it needs to be like this:

```
const before = ({ aFixture }) => {...}
test.beforeEach(before);
```